# How to merge two arrays and make it Sort,here it goes

Tags: c#, visual-c++

I am Currently looking for how to Sort an Array using Classes and Objects and how I can use it also in main Function instead of "Array.Sort();",I want to use my own created Sorting function instead of Using of Array.Sort(arr) Function

```
        int[] arr1 = new int[5] { 2, 5, 1, 7, 4 };//1st array declared
        int[] arr2 = new int[5] { 10, 16, 13, 17, 15 };
        int[] arr3 = new int[10];
        int k = 0;
        Console.WriteLine("First Array: ");
        for(int i=0;i<arr1.Length;i++)
        {
            Console.Write(" "+arr1[i]+" ");
        }

        Console.WriteLine("\nSecond Array: ");
        for(int x=0;x<arr2.Length;x++)
        {
            Console.Write(" " + arr2[x] + " ");
        }
        Console.WriteLine();

        Console.WriteLine("--------------MERGED ARRAY-------------");
        for (int i = 0; i < arr3.Length;i++)
        {
            if(i<arr1.Length)
            {

                arr3[i] = arr1[i];//Array 1 has been Stored in a new Array

            }
            else if (i >= arr1.Length)
            {

                arr3[i] = arr2[k];  //Array 2 has been Stored in a new Array                  
                k++;
            }
                Console.Write(" "+ arr3[i]+" ");


        }
        Console.WriteLine();
        Console.WriteLine("\n\n--------------------After Sorting---------------------");
        Array.Sort(arr3);//Sorting The merged Array
        foreach (int mainArr in arr3)
        {
            Console.Write(mainArr);
            Console.Write("  ");
        }
        Console.ReadKey();

     }
```

Hope This will be Helpful also.

Comment: Why exactly you'd like to use your own sorting function?

Comment: And what is your question?

Comment: Look at [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aw9s5t8f(v=vs.110).aspx), it will probably provide you with everything you need. Namely, implement the [IComparer](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.icomparer(v=vs.110).aspx) interface for the classes you put into array.

Comment: Why is this question marked C# AND C++? Furtheremore be a bit more specific on your actual problem? What do you expect? What do you get instead?

Answer (score 0):

You're writing too much code than needed, you can simply use Linq:

```
int[] arr1 = new int[5] { 2, 5, 1, 7, 4 };
int[] arr2 = new int[5] { 10, 16, 13, 17, 15 };
int[] arr3 = arr1.Concat(arr2).OrderBy(x => x).ToArray();
```

Comment: Actually I feel free to write every logic instead of using library function,I know it might be simplified,but this is not what I am looking for

Comment: @HamdanKaiser What is the custom sorting that you're trying to do ? What is the expected output ? Please be specific.

Comment: That Line int[] arr3 = arr1.Concat(arr2).OrderBy(x => x).ToArray();
is not giving me the exact output,i suggest you have a look please

Comment: @HamdanKaiser We don't even know what is the expected output. The above code merges the two lists and then sorts the outcome ascending. `1 2 4 5 7 10 13 15 16 17` What is the output that you expect ?

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of sorting algorithms, i wrote a pseudo code which will be easy to convert to C# (left you some work) for a very simple algorithm, it basically looks for the smallest element and put it to the left:

```
declare min = 0, i, k

for i=0 to array length

   for k=i+1 to array length

   if array[k] < array[i] then
     swap array[i] , array[k]


--------------------

swap a,b:

declare temp =  a

a=b

b=temp
```

Good luck!